# PHP Class not Returning Result

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

I am working on an Item Inventory Web App. I want users should be able to add and assign item to a user. Each user is entitled to one item at a time. If, say, user a already has an item assigned and you want to add more item, the system should lodge an error that will tell you 
to withdraw the item be issuing a new one but the errors are not getting lodged in the `error[]` array even though it shows that the array is not empty. It only echo out the serial number `a = 1 and a++` but the text is not there.

**class.inc.php**

```
class Summary {
    public $result;
    public $conn;
    public $SQ;
    public $q;
    public $updateDB;
    public $checkDB;
    public $returned_result;
    public $a;
    public $data;
    public $col;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dB', 'root', '');
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO:: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    public function updateDB($coloumn, $data, $id){
        $SQ = "UPDATE mytable SET $coloumn = ? WHERE staffID = ?";
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($SQ) or die("ERROR: " . implode(":", $this->conn->errorInfo()));
        $q->bindParam(1, $data);
        $q->bindParam(2, $id);
        if ($q->execute()){
            $success = 'Record updated successfully';
        };
        return $success;
    }

    public function checkDB($col, $data){
        $status = 'Active';
        $SQ = "SELECT surname FROM mytable WHERE $col = ? AND status = ?";
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($SQ) or die("ERROR: " . implode(":", $this->conn->errorInfo()));
        $q->bindParam(1, $data);
        $q->bindParam(2, $status);
        $q->execute();
        if($result = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
            $a = $result[0];
            if ($a == ''){
                $this->returned_result = 'N';
            }
            else {
                $this->returned_result = "This item (". $data . ") is in use by ". $a . ". Please widthraw the item";
            }
        }
        return $this->returned_result;
    }
}
```

**index.php:**

```
include('class.inc.php');
$summary = new Summary;
$error = array();
if(isset($_POST['saveRecord']) ) {
$system_name = strtoupper ( $_POST['system_name'] );
$result =$summary->checkDB('systemName', $system_name); //check if the item is in use
if ( $result == 'N' ){
    $summary->updateDB('systemName', $system_name, $id);
    $update = $summary->updateDB;
}
else $error[] = $result;


$system_serial_number = strtoupper ( $_POST['system_serial_number'] );

$result =$summary->checkDB('CPUSerial', $system_serial_number); //check if the item is in use
if ( $result == 'N' ){
    $summary->updateDB('CPUSerial', $system_serial_number, $id);
    $update = $summary->updateDB;
}
else $error[] = $result;
}

if(isset($_POST['saveRecord']) && !empty( $error ) ) {
echo "<div class = 'text-error'>";
$a = 1;
foreach ($error as $err){
    echo '<p>' . $a . '. ' .$err . '</p>';
    $a++;
}
echo "</div>";
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. And what am I doing wrong with regards to `OOP` way of programming?